# Was Luke with Paul when he travelled from Troas to Samothrace

Tags: acts

1. I am just curious about this text in Acts.
2. Seems like Luke was with Paul on this trip. Is this true?
3. Please see the highlighted word **we**

> **Acts 16:10** After Paul had seen the vision, **we got ready** at once to leave for Macedonia, concluding that God had called us to preach the gospel to them. **11** From Troas **we put out to sea** and sailed straight for Samothrace, and the next day we went on to Neapolis. **12** From there **we traveled** to Philippi, a Roman colony and the leading city of that district[a] of Macedonia. And **we stayed there** several days. **13** On the Sabbath we went outside the city gate to the river, where we expected to find a place of prayer. **We sat down** and began to speak to the women who had gathered there. **14** One of those listening was a woman from the city of Thyatira named Lydia, a dealer in purple cloth. She was a worshiper of God. The Lord opened her heart to respond to Paul’s message. **15** When she and the members of her household were baptized, she invited us to her home. “If you consider me a believer in the Lord,” she said, “come and stay at my house.” And she persuaded us. **16** Once when **we were going** to the place of prayer, we were met by a female slave who had a spirit by which she predicted the future. She earned a great deal of money for her owners by fortune-telling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acts 16:

> 6 **Paul and his companions** traveled throughout the region of Phrygia and Galatia, having been kept by the Holy Spirit from preaching the word in the province of Asia. 7When **they** came to the border of Mysia, **they** tried to enter Bithynia, but the Spirit of Jesus would not allow **them** to. 8So **they** passed by Mysia and went down to Troas. 9During the night Paul had a vision of a man of Macedonia standing and begging him, “Come over to Macedonia and help us.”

So far, it was "they" and "them". Then the pronoun changed to "we".

> 10 After Paul had seen the vision, **we** got ready at once to leave for Macedonia, concluding that God had called us to preach the gospel to them.

At this point, Luke joined Paul.

Commentators at
https://biblehub.com/commentaries/acts/16-10.htm agree. E.g., Pulpit:

> It is quite characteristic of Holy Scripture that things are told, or appear on the face of the narrative, without any explanation. Who **Luke** was, what brought him to Troas, how he became a companion of St. Paul, whether as his medical adviser or otherwise, we know not. His Christian modesty forbade his speaking about himself.